# PHP profiler that outputs to HTML file

Tags: php, profiler

I would like to know if there is a profiler out there that will output the profile of running segments of PHP to a separate HTML (or other reader friendly type of file) file that resides on the server, or at least a plain text log file? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "running segments of PHP" - PHP processes? Instances in an Cloud env?

Comment: Just contiguous snippets (of any # of lines of code) of plain PHP code within a PHP file

Comment: xhprof - https://github.com/facebook/xhprof

Comment: I actually have xhprof installed and working. But when I click certain buttons, which trigger AJAX and not a page load or reload, xhprof does not generate runs for those types of triggers. It only seems to generate reports for page loads.

Comment: The buttons merely display popups and don't load any new pages. xhprof does not appear to notice these (by default anyway).

Comment: The only way to gaurantee PHP being run gets logged appears to be having it being printed from the PHP to a separate file. In which case a tool that prints it such that it's reader friendly and does most of the work would be ideal.

Comment: you are writing "the buttons ... don't load any new pages" - are you using Jquery's load to fetch the popup content from the backend? Just a silly idea: is the content you are fetching parsed by PHP at all? (like .html is often non parsed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that addresses my problem beautifully. Downloaded xdebug with Webgrind front end and it has no problem generating reports for AJAX (running PHP). All the other profilers I've used won't do this.